# Maximize the diff of elements of Two Arrays B[j] − A[i] where j > i

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is not the max-profit algorithm, but a variation of it.

I have an array `A`, where `A[i]` corresponds to the price of computers in **country A** and time `i`. And `B[i]` corresponds to the price of computers in **country B** and time `i`.

All entries in each array are positive integers. I want to buy computers in **country A** at some time `i` and then sell them in **country B** at some later time `j > i`.

I need to **maximize profit** `B[j] − A[i]`.

**Example:**

```
A = [40, 18, 20, 25, 12, 13, 19, 20, 5, 7, 3]

B = [15, 50, 5, 30, 34, 19, 28, 33, 20, 20, 20]
```

The maximum possible profit is `B[7] − A[4] = 33 − 12 = 21`, so the output should be `21`.

I want this to run in **O(n)**.

This is what I have so far.

```
static int maxProfit(int pricesA[], int pricesB[]) {
     
        int maxProfit = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < pricesA.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 1; j < pricesB.length; j++) {
                 if (pricesB[j - 1] > pricesA[i]) {
                    maxProfit = pricesB[j - 1] - pricesA[i];
                 }
            }
        }
            return maxProfit;
    }
```

However, I'm having trouble with getting the selling the computer at a time `j > i` part. Right now, I'm comparing every time in `B[j]` with `A[i]` when it should be that I buy at time `A[i]` and sell it for a profit at time `B[j]` where index `j` is greater than index `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that in **O(n)** time you can use the logic that very is similar to ***Kadane's algorithm*** for finding the maximum sum of a sub-array.

The overall idea is to track the **minimum price** previously encountered for *country A*.

And at each step of iteration, compare the profit that can be obtained by selling the computers at the current price `B[i]` (*assuming that they were bought at a minimum price* `minA`) with the **maximum profit**.

**Minimum price** for country *A* `minA` initialized with the first element in the array `countryA[0]`. And at each iteration step it's being compared with the value of element `countryA[i - 1]`.

The  best possible **profit** for each step will be `countryB[i] - minA`, where `minA` is the smallest value among `countryA[0] ... countryA[i - 1]`.

The case when the given arrays are of *different length* or comprised of *less than* `2` elements represents the situation when the *input data is incorrect*, therefore `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

```
public static int getMaxProfit(int[] countryA, int[] countryB) {
    if (countryA.length != countryB.length || // will lead to IndexOutOfBoundsException
            countryB.length < 2) { // impossible to fulfil requirement: B[j] - A[i] where j > i
        
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int minA = countryA[0];
    int maxProfit = countryB[1] - countryA[0];

    for (int i = 2; i < countryB.length; i++) {
        minA = Math.min(countryA[i - 1], minA);
        maxProfit = Math.max(countryB[i] - minA, maxProfit);
    }
    return maxProfit;
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] countryA = {40, 18, 20, 25, 12, 13, 19, 20, 5, 7, 3};
    int[] countryB = {15, 50, 5, 30, 34, 19, 28, 33, 20, 20, 20};

    System.out.println(getMaxProfit(countryA, countryB));
}
```

**Output**

```
21
```

Comment: How is that Kadane's algorithm?

Comment: @KellyBundy Literally spiking it's not, I've amended the statement. But the logic is very similar: track the global maximum and compare it with the local maximum at each iteration step.

Comment: Somewhat similar, yes, but also quite different. I think this is simpler and the Kadane name drop looks artificial.